# How to get the height of generic type item swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function (in an UIViewController extension) which needs to take a generic type (because I could be passing in a button, a UITextField, etc). In that function I need to find the heigh and width of the generic type (button, UITextField, etc). I am using this info to be able to scroll up the page based on the keyboard height to make the button or whatever it is visible. The code for it is down below.

```
extension UIViewController {
       func scrollUpKeyboard<Object>(object: Object, keyboardHeight: CGFloat, realOrigin: 
           CGPoint) {
       var buttonHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - (object.frame.size.height + 
           realOrigin.y)
        
        if keyboardHeight > buttonHeight {
            self.ScrollUpFromKeyboard(amount: keyboardHeight - buttonHeight)
        } else {
             self.ScrollUpFromKeyboard(amount: -10)
             
        }
   }
// More code
}
```

The error I'm getting is "Value of type 'Object' has no member 'frame'." How do I get the height and width of the generic object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't generic objects. They're all UIViews, which is a superclass. You can just pass that:

```
func scrollUpKeyboard(object: UIView, ...
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!